# Edit hyperref PDF metadata and options in external software

Tags: hyperref, pdf, viewers, tools, metadata

I am looking to figure out whether there is a way to edit options that the `hyperref` package offers in other software. To be more precise, what I am particularly after are the following ones:

```
pdftitle={ },
pdfauthor={ },
pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
pdfpagelayout={SinglePage}
```

In other words, is there any other software (outside the LaTeX side) which offers the options to edit these values? If so, would it be possible to direct me towards those?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Pro can do this.

Comment: From `pdftk` manpage: `pdftk in.pdf update_info in.info output out.pdf`, however, I am not sure, if this really works and I never tried it

Comment: This is off-topic for us, I think, as you seem to want a non-TeX solution. SuperUser would be the obvious place to ask but the way it's currently phrased will not work there: can you edit to make it about PDF metadata without the `hyperref` part?

Comment: @JosephWright I don’t think it’s a great fit either, but since it is about pdfs – which *TeX users deal with a lot and some people here know a great lot about them – I would propose to “tolerate” it here as being about “related software and tools”, particularly because it’s just an interesting question. One might even say that pdf tools are pretty closely related to *TeX.

Comment: Yes, I knew it was slightly offtopic with regards to a TeX solution but I figured it might work since PDFs seem to be most advanced when generated through TeX -- and in a way the selling point is that if you generate a PDF you can open it in any software. So the question of whether you can edit it in other software is similarly relevant, I would say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) by Tracker Software (free unlimited demo version, Windoze only), which seems to have been superseded by [PDF-XChange Editor](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor). I assume the latter has the same capabilities with respect to this question, but I haven’t checked it out. Also, I’m not affiliated with this company in any way. There are limitations to the free/demo version, but it works for what we’re trying to do here.

So I created a LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftitle={My Title}, pdfauthor={A. Author},
            pdfdisplaydoctitle=true, pdfpagelayout={SinglePage}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

... compiled, opened the pdf in PDF-XChange Viewer, and went into the document properties, which you can edit as you please.

[image: Window: Document Properties – Description]

[image: Window: Document Properties – Initial View]

Comment: Cheers; this seems to have all the capability that I was looking for. Thanks for a comprehensive answer!

Comment: My method uses only a text editor [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/z_VhS4F7Df4)